# Storing and comparing tree nodes in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following:

```
Map<MyNode, MyNode> nodes = new HashMap<MyNode, MyNode>();
```

This map won't ever be filled with more than 100 nodes at a time, so I don't really have to worry about overhead. But what I am trying to do is when I create a new Node, and set the contents of the node. I want to check if the Node with the exact same contents already exist in the map. I was originally doing

> maps.containskey();

but I realized that they don't have the same signature. So even though there might be a Node with the exact same content, to Java they are different. My question is how can I store a node in the Map, and be able to check if a Node with exact same contents already exists?

```
class MyNode
    {
        boolean end = false;
        Map<String, MyNode> edges = new HashMap<String, MyNode>();
    }
```

I haven't wrote my own hashcode or equal. I figured if I use containskey it will tell me if they are equal

Comment: What map are you using? New map() does not exist, map is an interface.

Comment: And can you post your Node class with hashcode() and equals() methods

Answer (score 1):

Use your own object. Don't use a `Node` object unless you can modify it. Use your own created `Object` and override the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) methods to determine if two such objects are unique. Then everything will work as expected with respect to `containsKey()` and any other approach.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Node is actually my own Object I didn't realize that Java has it's own Node. I haven't overwritten equals() and hashCode() in my Node. I just figured if I use containsKey it will find me the one that is equal

Comment: @JohshHanks That's not how containsKey works. Read up on equals and hashCode and you will understand why you need to implement them, and how. It's very easy and it's a good thing to know.